# WiX: register .NET COM component both x86 x64

Tags: .net, com, wix, 64-bit

I have C# COM .dll. I would like to install the .dll once, but have it be registered for both x86 and x64.

Here's the WiX I have for registering only x64:

```
<Component Id="NETDLL.dll" Directory="INSTALLDIR">
  <File Id="NETDLL.dll" Name="NETDLL.dll" KeyPath="yes" Source="..\NETDLL.dll" />
  <Class Id="{78BE...}" Context="InprocServer32" Description="NETDLL" ThreadingModel="both" ForeignServer="mscoree.dll">
    <ProgId Id="NETDLL" Description="NETDLL" />
  </Class>
  <RegistryValue Root="HKCR" Key="CLSID\{78BE...}\Implemented Categories\{62C8FE65-4EBB-45e7-B440-6E39B2CDBF29}" Value="" Type="string" Action="write" />
  <RegistryValue Root="HKCR" Key="CLSID\{78BE...}\InprocServer32\1.0.1.0" Name="Class" Value="NETDLL" Type="string" Action="write" />
  <RegistryValue Root="HKCR" Key="CLSID\{78BE...}\InprocServer32\1.0.1.0" Name="Assembly" Value="NETDLL, Version=1.0.1.0, Culture=neutral" Type="string" Action="write" />
  <RegistryValue Root="HKCR" Key="CLSID\{78BE...}\InprocServer32\1.0.1.0" Name="RuntimeVersion" Value="v4.0.30319" Type="string" Action="write" />
  <RegistryValue Root="HKCR" Key="CLSID\{78BE...}\InprocServer32\1.0.1.0" Name="CodeBase" Value="file:///[#NETDLL.dll]" Type="string" Action="write" />
  <RegistryValue Root="HKCR" Key="CLSID\{78BE...}\InprocServer32" Name="Class" Value="NETDLL" Type="string" Action="write" />
  <RegistryValue Root="HKCR" Key="CLSID\{78BE...}\InprocServer32" Name="Assembly" Value="NETDLL, Version=1.0.1.0, Culture=neutral" Type="string" Action="write" />
  <RegistryValue Root="HKCR" Key="CLSID\{78BE...}\InprocServer32" Name="RuntimeVersion" Value="v4.0.30319" Type="string" Action="write" />
  <RegistryValue Root="HKCR" Key="CLSID\{78BE...}\InprocServer32" Name="CodeBase" Value="file:///[#NETDLL.dll]" Type="string" Action="write" />
  <RegistryValue Root="HKCR" Key="Component Categories\{62C8FE65-4EBB-45e7-B440-6E39B2CDBF29}" Name="0" Value=".NET Category" Type="string" Action="write" />
  <RegistryKey Root='HKLM' Key='Software\NETDLL'>
    <RegistryValue Name='Description' Type='string' Value='NETDLL'/>
  </RegistryKey>
</Component>
```

How can I write in HKCR\CLSID, HKCR\Wow6432Node\CLSID, HKLM\Software, and HKLM\Software\Wow6432Node all at once?

Answer (score 1):

I succeeded registering the same dll on a 64 Bit System for x86 and 64bit by playing around with two Components, one for the 64bit and one for the x86 Registration:

```
<Component Id="NETDLL.dll" Directory="INSTALLDIR" Guid="*">
   <Class Id="{78BE...}" Context="InprocServer32" Description="NETDLL"  
        ThreadingModel="both" ForeignServer="mscoree.dll">
      <ProgId Id="NETDLL" Description="NETDLL" />
   </Class>
   <File Id="NETDLL.dll" Name="NETDLL.dll" KeyPath="yes" 
          Source="..\NETDLL.dll" />
   <RegistryValue Root="HKCR" Key="CLSID\{78BE...}\Implemented Categories {62C8FE65-4EBB-45e7-B440-6E39B2CDBF29}" Value="" Type="string" Action="write" />
   ...
</Component>
<Component Id="NETDLLWin64.dll" Guid="{885F75B1-3046-42BD-8B37-F8FA0E8D7A51}" Win64="yes" Directory="INSTALLDIR">
   <Class Id="{78BE...}" Context="InprocServer32" Description="NETDLL" ThreadingModel="both" ForeignServer="mscoree.dll">
      <ProgId Id="NETDLL" Description="NETDLL" />
   </Class>
   <RegistryValue Root="HKCR" Key="CLSID\{78BE...}\Implemented Categories\{62C8FE65-4EBB-45e7-B440-6E39B2CDBF29}" Value="" Type="string" Action="write" />  
   ...
</Component>
```

I added **Guid**-Attributes in the Component Node, changed the Id for the second Component and added the **Win64="yes"** Attribut. Also I don't duplicate the File. Hope this helps, if you have a lot of dependencies and won't duplicate the Files.

Answer (score 0):

Try the `regasm.exe` switches /x86 and /x64.

You also have 32-bit and 64-bit versions of `regasm.exe` , one in `C:\windows\microsoft .net\<version>\Framework` and another in `Framework64`, see if that helps.

Comment: Writing CustomActions is a pain, and leaves me in doubt that it will work with uninstall or rollback. Seems like I would need to execute `reg.exe` too to add values to HKLM.

Comment: regasm.exe doesn't support the /x86 or /x64 command line switches.

Answer (score 0):

Install two copies of the file, one each under `ProgramFiles64Folder` and `ProgramFilesFolder`. Wastes .5MiB, but is simple.

Comment: Does this require that you compile the .NET assembly with AnyCPU?