# Using wix to install a Shell Extension x64 and put the extension assembly in the GAC

Tags: wix, installation, windows-installer

I have created a shell extension Library.  If I use regasm x64 to register it with the codebase switch it works fine.  I am now trying to put it into an package to deploy.

I have created a Wix project in VS2010 which is for x64.  Product platform is x64.  Now currently I am putting the file in the GAC with this.

```
<Fragment>
<ComponentGroup Id="ProductComponents" Directory="INSTALLFOLDER">
  <!-- MYAppConnect.dll -->
  <Component Id="com_MYAppContextMenu.dll" Guid="*" Win64="yes">
    <File Id="file_MYAppContextMenu.dll" Name="MYAppContextMenu.dll" 
          Assembly=".net" Source="..\..\MYAppContextMenu\MYAppContextMenu.dll" 
          KeyPath="yes"/>
  </Component>
</ComponentGroup>
```

I then used Heat.exe to get my registry stuff which produces this.  File is in the GAC - the below registry settings are in the expected place - not in the wow64 hive.

So I assume I am doing something wrong.  Could someone give me some tips, comments or direction on what to do.

```
<Fragment>
<DirectoryRef Id="TARGETDIR">
  <Directory Id="dir29DD73560741DA307F10310D0631A50A" Name="MYAppContextMenu" />
</DirectoryRef>
</Fragment>
<Fragment>
<DirectoryRef Id="dir29DD73560741DA307F10310D0631A50A">
  <Component Id="cmp322F9BBA6F4BF4E5180AB10BED5E416D" Guid="*" Win64="yes">
    <Class Id="{3E9DE1E3-7B57-43A6-AA05-6CAF8018F450}" Context="InprocServer32" Description="MYAppContextMenu.FileContextMenuExt" ThreadingModel="both" ForeignServer="mscoree.dll">
      <ProgId Id="MYAppContextMenu.FileContextMenuExt" Description="MYAppContextMenu.FileContextMenuExt" />
    </Class>
    <File Id="filCCBAC28E458283F290F1DB9F69EC2BF1" KeyPath="yes" Source="..\..\MYAppContextMenu\MYAppContextMenu.dll" />
    <RegistryValue Root="HKCR" Key=".asc\shellex\ContextMenuHandlers\{3e9de1e3-7b57-43a6-aa05-6caf8018f450}" Value="MYAppContextMenu.TDBSContextMenu Class" Type="string" Action="write" />
    <RegistryValue Root="HKCR" Key=".csv\shellex\ContextMenuHandlers\{3e9de1e3-7b57-43a6-aa05-6caf8018f450}" Value="MYAppContextMenu.TDBSContextMenu Class" Type="string" Action="write" />
    <RegistryValue Root="HKCR" Key=".doc\shellex\ContextMenuHandlers\{3e9de1e3-7b57-43a6-aa05-6caf8018f450}" Value="MYAppContextMenu.TDBSContextMenu Class" Type="string" Action="write" />
    <RegistryValue Root="HKCR" Key=".docm\shellex\ContextMenuHandlers\{3e9de1e3-7b57-43a6-aa05-6caf8018f450}" Value="MYAppContextMenu.TDBSContextMenu Class" Type="string" Action="write" />
    <RegistryValue Root="HKCR" Key=".docx\shellex\ContextMenuHandlers\{3e9de1e3-7b57-43a6-aa05-6caf8018f450}" Value="MYAppContextMenu.TDBSContextMenu Class" Type="string" Action="write" />
    <RegistryValue Root="HKCR" Key=".gif\shellex\ContextMenuHandlers\{3e9de1e3-7b57-43a6-aa05-6caf8018f450}" Value="MYAppContextMenu.TDBSContextMenu Class" Type="string" Action="write" />
    <RegistryValue Root="HKCR" Key=".jpeg\shellex\ContextMenuHandlers\{3e9de1e3-7b57-43a6-aa05-6caf8018f450}" Value="MYAppContextMenu.TDBSContextMenu Class" Type="string" Action="write" />
    <RegistryValue Root="HKCR" Key=".jpg\shellex\ContextMenuHandlers\{3e9de1e3-7b57-43a6-aa05-6caf8018f450}" Value="MYAppContextMenu.TDBSContextMenu Class" Type="string" Action="write" />
    <RegistryValue Root="HKCR" Key=".log\shellex\ContextMenuHandlers\{3e9de1e3-7b57-43a6-aa05-6caf8018f450}" Value="MYAppContextMenu.TDBSContextMenu Class" Type="string" Action="write" />
    <RegistryValue Root="HKCR" Key=".msg\shellex\ContextMenuHandlers\{3e9de1e3-7b57-43a6-aa05-6caf8018f450}" Value="MYAppContextMenu.TDBSContextMenu Class" Type="string" Action="write" />
    <RegistryValue Root="HKCR" Key=".ods\shellex\ContextMenuHandlers\{3e9de1e3-7b57-43a6-aa05-6caf8018f450}" Value="MYAppContextMenu.TDBSContextMenu Class" Type="string" Action="write" />
    <RegistryValue Root="HKCR" Key=".odt\shellex\ContextMenuHandlers\{3e9de1e3-7b57-43a6-aa05-6caf8018f450}" Value="MYAppContextMenu.TDBSContextMenu Class" Type="string" Action="write" />
    <RegistryValue Root="HKCR" Key=".ott\shellex\ContextMenuHandlers\{3e9de1e3-7b57-43a6-aa05-6caf8018f450}" Value="MYAppContextMenu.TDBSContextMenu Class" Type="string" Action="write" />
    <RegistryValue Root="HKCR" Key=".pdf\shellex\ContextMenuHandlers\{3e9de1e3-7b57-43a6-aa05-6caf8018f450}" Value="MYAppContextMenu.TDBSContextMenu Class" Type="string" Action="write" />
    <RegistryValue Root="HKCR" Key=".png\shellex\ContextMenuHandlers\{3e9de1e3-7b57-43a6-aa05-6caf8018f450}" Value="MYAppContextMenu.TDBSContextMenu Class" Type="string" Action="write" />
    <RegistryValue Root="HKCR" Key=".ppt\shellex\ContextMenuHandlers\{3e9de1e3-7b57-43a6-aa05-6caf8018f450}" Value="MYAppContextMenu.TDBSContextMenu Class" Type="string" Action="write" />
    <RegistryValue Root="HKCR" Key=".pptm\shellex\ContextMenuHandlers\{3e9de1e3-7b57-43a6-aa05-6caf8018f450}" Value="MYAppContextMenu.TDBSContextMenu Class" Type="string" Action="write" />
    <RegistryValue Root="HKCR" Key=".pptx\shellex\ContextMenuHandlers\{3e9de1e3-7b57-43a6-aa05-6caf8018f450}" Value="MYAppContextMenu.TDBSContextMenu Class" Type="string" Action="write" />
    <RegistryValue Root="HKCR" Key=".raw\shellex\ContextMenuHandlers\{3e9de1e3-7b57-43a6-aa05-6caf8018f450}" Value="MYAppContextMenu.TDBSContextMenu Class" Type="string" Action="write" />
    <RegistryValue Root="HKCR" Key=".rtf\shellex\ContextMenuHandlers\{3e9de1e3-7b57-43a6-aa05-6caf8018f450}" Value="MYAppContextMenu.TDBSContextMenu Class" Type="string" Action="write" />
    <RegistryValue Root="HKCR" Key=".tif\shellex\ContextMenuHandlers\{3e9de1e3-7b57-43a6-aa05-6caf8018f450}" Value="MYAppContextMenu.TDBSContextMenu Class" Type="string" Action="write" />
    <RegistryValue Root="HKCR" Key=".tiff\shellex\ContextMenuHandlers\{3e9de1e3-7b57-43a6-aa05-6caf8018f450}" Value="MYAppContextMenu.TDBSContextMenu Class" Type="string" Action="write" />
    <RegistryValue Root="HKCR" Key=".wps\shellex\ContextMenuHandlers\{3e9de1e3-7b57-43a6-aa05-6caf8018f450}" Value="MYAppContextMenu.TDBSContextMenu Class" Type="string" Action="write" />
    <RegistryValue Root="HKCR" Key=".xlm\shellex\ContextMenuHandlers\{3e9de1e3-7b57-43a6-aa05-6caf8018f450}" Value="MYAppContextMenu.TDBSContextMenu Class" Type="string" Action="write" />
    <RegistryValue Root="HKCR" Key=".xls\shellex\ContextMenuHandlers\{3e9de1e3-7b57-43a6-aa05-6caf8018f450}" Value="MYAppContextMenu.TDBSContextMenu Class" Type="string" Action="write" />
    <RegistryValue Root="HKCR" Key=".xlsm\shellex\ContextMenuHandlers\{3e9de1e3-7b57-43a6-aa05-6caf8018f450}" Value="MYAppContextMenu.TDBSContextMenu Class" Type="string" Action="write" />
    <RegistryValue Root="HKCR" Key=".xlsx\shellex\ContextMenuHandlers\{3e9de1e3-7b57-43a6-aa05-6caf8018f450}" Value="MYAppContextMenu.TDBSContextMenu Class" Type="string" Action="write" />
    <RegistryValue Root="HKCR" Key=".xps\shellex\ContextMenuHandlers\{3e9de1e3-7b57-43a6-aa05-6caf8018f450}" Value="MYAppContextMenu.TDBSContextMenu Class" Type="string" Action="write" />
    <RegistryValue Root="HKCR" Key=".zip\shellex\ContextMenuHandlers\{3e9de1e3-7b57-43a6-aa05-6caf8018f450}" Value="MYAppContextMenu.TDBSContextMenu Class" Type="string" Action="write" />
    <RegistryValue Root="HKCR" Key="CLSID\{3E9DE1E3-7B57-43A6-AA05-6CAF8018F450}\Implemented Categories\{62C8FE65-4EBB-45e7-B440-6E39B2CDBF29}" Value="" Type="string" Action="write" />
    <RegistryValue Root="HKCR" Key="CLSID\{3E9DE1E3-7B57-43A6-AA05-6CAF8018F450}\InprocServer32\1.0.0.0" Name="Class" Value="MYAppContextMenu.FileContextMenuExt" Type="string" Action="write" />
    <RegistryValue Root="HKCR" Key="CLSID\{3E9DE1E3-7B57-43A6-AA05-6CAF8018F450}\InprocServer32\1.0.0.0" Name="Assembly" Value="MYAppContextMenu, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=448edde23f8b5bbd" Type="string" Action="write" />
    <RegistryValue Root="HKCR" Key="CLSID\{3E9DE1E3-7B57-43A6-AA05-6CAF8018F450}\InprocServer32\1.0.0.0" Name="RuntimeVersion" Value="v4.0.30319" Type="string" Action="write" />
    <RegistryValue Root="HKCR" Key="CLSID\{3E9DE1E3-7B57-43A6-AA05-6CAF8018F450}\InprocServer32\1.0.0.0" Name="CodeBase" Value="file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/MYAppContextMenu/v4.0_1.0.0.0__448edde23f8b5bbd/MYAppContextMenu.dll" Type="string" Action="write" />
    <RegistryValue Root="HKCR" Key="CLSID\{3E9DE1E3-7B57-43A6-AA05-6CAF8018F450}\InprocServer32" Name="Class" Value="MYAppContextMenu.FileContextMenuExt" Type="string" Action="write" />
    <RegistryValue Root="HKCR" Key="CLSID\{3E9DE1E3-7B57-43A6-AA05-6CAF8018F450}\InprocServer32" Name="Assembly" Value="MYAppContextMenu, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=448edde23f8b5bbd" Type="string" Action="write" />
    <RegistryValue Root="HKCR" Key="CLSID\{3E9DE1E3-7B57-43A6-AA05-6CAF8018F450}\InprocServer32" Name="RuntimeVersion" Value="v4.0.30319" Type="string" Action="write" />
    <RegistryValue Root="HKCR" Key="CLSID\{3E9DE1E3-7B57-43A6-AA05-6CAF8018F450}\InprocServer32" Name="CodeBase" Value="file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.Net/assembly/GAC_MSIL/MYAppContextMenu/v4.0_1.0.0.0__448edde23f8b5bbd/MYAppContextMenu.dll" Type="string" Action="write" />
  </Component>
</DirectoryRef>
</Fragment>
```

Comment: Why install this file to the GAC? Btw, you already do install to the GAC by setting Assembly=".net", no need to set a GAC directory as far as I know. I would install it outside the GAC to avoid its idiosyncrazies. I am not familiar with x64 registration, but it looks odd with InprocServer32 as part of the registration? Perhaps try [this advice](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11276203/129130).

Comment: Because that is at least highly recommended.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to add a dll to GAC, can you try this? This will copy the dll to GAC when the feature is selected.

Feature definition

```
 <Feature Id="Feature1" Title="Deploy dlls" Level="1">
  <ComponentGroupRef Id="InfragisticsRunTime" />
</Feature>
```

Directory definition

```
<Directory Id="TARGETDIR" Name="SourceDir">
  <Directory Id="CompanyName" Name="Some Company Name">
   <Directory Id="INSTALLLOCATIONCONFIG" Name="Some Files">
   </Directory>
   <Directory Id="GAC" Name="GAC"> <!--Just a refrence-->
   </Directory>
 </Directory>  
</Directory>
```

ComponentGroup definition

```
<Fragment>
        <ComponentGroup Id="InfragisticsRunTime">
            <ComponentRef Id="cmp79447E1633608740D07286A035DEFFB3" />
        </ComponentGroup>
</Fragment>
```

Component definition

```
<Fragment>
<Component Id="cmp79447E1633608740D07286A035DEFFB3" Directory="GAC" Guid="*">
 <File Id="filB48E30816BA7EF62BABB08A480F1E6BB" KeyPath="yes" 
       Source=".\Infragistics\Infragistics2.Documents.Core.v12.1.dll" 
       Assembly=".net" />
 </Component>
 </Fragment>
```

Comment: Thank you.  But this has not changed my situation. File is in the GAC and the registry for the shell extension "looks" perfect.  But no menus.

Comment: Suggestions: 1. Run regasm on your dll with the /regfile option just to compare with what you have in WiX, a sanity check. 2. Do a COM call on your Dll with a CreateObject ("progid") or with CLSID and see what happens, use the Fusion Log Viewer to see why it fails. 3. Regasm also creates type library interface registry entries, so it's vaguely possible you need to create a tlb file and heat that to get the Interface registry entries.